# SQL+PHP: how can i return all PHP array existed values from SQL table?

Tags: php, mysql

**Hello All**

I have a simple php array, For Example:

```
$numbers=array("12345","65432","98765");
```

And SQL **Table** named: "phones" with the **column** "TNumbers" and the **rows**: 654654, 12345, 87878.

Now, What will be the fastest way to return all the values from the array that exist in the SQL server table? (So it should return only this: ("12345"))

**Thank you Very Much!!**

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) See [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice), please.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp

Comment: use IN clause in your sql, set into it implode(',', $numbers)

Comment: @Misch please see http://w3fools.com/

Comment: @LukasKnuth thanks for the info, I always thought of w3schools being an official W3C website. I just used the first result for the google search "sql in".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more search i have found the answer, Sorry for that:

```
$ids = join(',',$numbers);  
$sql = "SELECT * FROM phones WHERE TNumbers IN ($ids)";
```

**Thank you anyway!**

Comment: this is prone to SQL injections, so make sure that your `$numbers` array doesn't contain malicious code!